# how to know the ie's table is closed but not refreshed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to do somethin when users closing my webs.  So I'd done like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    #do something 
}
```

But it's dispoint that I can't know the uers is doing close or not, because it's also can be refresh (like F5);
do anybody would like to help me?